# Generic method won't accept parameter, given error saying to create method w/ non-generic param

Tags: java, generics

I am confused about why my generic method will not accept a non-generic parameter. I've written a generic sort using compareTo, and am trying to test it by passing an array of ints into it, however I keep getting an error and eclipse tells me to create a method that accepts int arrays. Been digging around online but I can't see what I'm doing wrong, any clues?

main:

```
 public static int[] arrayTen = new int[10];
 public static int[] arrayHundred = new int[100];
 public static int[] arrayThousand = new int[1000];
 public static int[] arrayMillion = new int[1000000];

 public static void main (String[] args){

    Sorts selection = new Sorts();

    //generate four arrays to test speeds
    arrayGenerator();


    Sorts.selectionSort(arrayTen);

    }
```

generic Sort:

```
/**
 * Selection Sort
 * @param array[] a
 */
public static < E extends Comparable<E>> void selectionSort (E[] a){

    for (int i = 0 ; i < (a.length - 1) ; i++){
        int smallestNum = i; //index of the smallest number/character/element
        for (int x = i + 1; x < a.length; x++){
            if (a[x].compareTo(a[smallestNum])<=0){ //compare two elements
                smallestNum = x;
            }
        }
        sort(a, i, smallestNum);
    }
}




/**
 * Swaps the smaller & larger numbers
 * @param array[] a
 * @param int b
 * @param int c
 */
private static <E> void sort ( E[] a, int b, int c ){
    if ( b != c){
        E temp = a[b];
        a[b] = a[c];
        a[c] = temp;
    }
}
```